# Using Google Font API in Google Web Toolkit

Tags: gwt, google-font-api

Are there any best practices for using [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) in a [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) application? My initial inclination is to simply add the css reference directly in my .html file, a la

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:light,regular,bold' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

But I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it. Is there any advantage to (or any way to) use ClientBundle here?

Answer (score 5):

Google discourages the direct inclusion of css files on host pages for a mere fact that in this case GWT code has an external (detached) dependence. This only matters if you share a GWT module with other developers - note that this might happen in the future when your project gets refactored by some other people that took over the development. So it's still a good practice to make GWT modules with type-safe external dependencies.

As you know you can simply use one of the recommended ways:

- Using a CssResource contained within a ClientBundle.
- Using an inline `<ui:style src="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin">` element in a UiBinder template.

Comment: Very helpful--thanks! I actually wasn't exactly sure how to approach injecting this via CssResource / ClientBundle